# Browser keeps loading fore ever (vite dev server)

Tags: server, vite

I start my vite dev server for my react typescript project.
After working for some time the browser is unable to serve the website and it keeps loading fore ever.
This also slows down my syatem internet speed

After i close the browser and server. The issue is resolved but it again appears after i work sometime on the server.

I am using linux mint as my OS

I have also tried upgrading the u limit as described in the vite js troubleshoot page but no help

Answer (score -1):

I'm also using Linux Mint and I followed the troubleshooting as Vite's documentation describe and it works for me. I hope it works for you as well.

I followed these steps:

- Increase file descriptor limit by `ulimit`:

```bash
# Check current limit
$ ulimit -Sn
# Change limit (temporary)
$ ulimit -Sn 10000 # You might need to change the hard limit too
# Restart your browser
```

Increase the following inotify related limits by `sysctl`:

```bash
# Check current limits
sysctl fs.inotify
# Change limits (temporary)
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_queued_events=16384
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_instances=8192
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
```

I added `DefaultLimitNOFILE=65536` as an un-commented config to the following files (as the documentation asked):

- /etc/systemd/system.conf
- /etc/systemd/user.conf

After these changes I had to **restart the system**.

Documentation reference: https://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#requests-are-stalled-forever